# unity how to create a function that change any boolean using button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

i have 100 booleans. but i do not want to create 100 different function to change each boolean (to prevent script from going too long).

i like a create just 1 function that can change selected boolean to true using button. end result i hope to have 100 buttons that can change each boolean using that one function.

for the image below on button on click, i was expecting a input field for selecting either of the boolean instead of the checkbox. any way to change that?

```
public bool bool1 = false;
public bool bool2 = false;
public bool bool3 = false;
....
public bool bool100 = false;

public void ChangeBool(bool a)
{
    a = true;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dThfv.png)

Comment: Why not just use [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)?

Comment: do you mean the following?

    public bool Bolean(bool a)
    {
        get { return a; }
        set
        {
            a = true;
        }
    }

Comment: The link I posted explains how to use properties. Create a property for each of your booleans and use the fields as backing fields. Inside `get` and `set` you can add any logic you need. It would be convoluted and counterproductive to have a single method that changes all of them. Just use properties and set them to whatever you need them to be set to.

Comment: Oh wait I think I misunderstood the question. I think you're looking for the [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) keyword.

Comment: TBBH it starts with 'I've got a 100 booleans", not to be an asshole here (and yes I am) but that's already a codesmell to begin with

Comment: im trying to create a game with 100 stages. upon completion of each stage, there will be a reward at the end of each stage. each reward can only be collected once. i like to use the boolean to track the completion of each stage (eg bool stage1completed) to prevent players from going back to the same stage to claim the same reward again. yet not closing off that particular stage. is there a better solution other than this boolean approach?

Comment: Instead of having a single field for each stage, why not have a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0) where the key is an identifier for the stage and the value is a boolean indicating whether or not it's done? This solution is generally a lot cleaner and makes adding new stages easy because it can be completely dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) keyword. As the name implies, this keyword indicates that a reference will be passed to the function rather than just the value (for [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types)). This means you can set the input parameter using the `ref` keyword and the variable passed to the method will be changed as well.

```cs
public static void ChangeBool(ref bool a)
{
    a = true;
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var b = false;
ChangeBool(ref b);
Console.WriteLine(b) // Prints "True"
```

[Here's a .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BUyveg) with a working example.

---

However, I fail to see how this is any better than just setting the variable itself to `true`.

Comment: i tried your solution.  unfortunately, for the inspector> button on click(), cannot detect the function. therefore unable to attach it to a button

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Unity so I unfortunately don't know why it won't let you attach it to a button.

Comment: no worries. you have been a great help. i correct myself in regards to "attach". the script can be attached but just that the button cannot detect the function upon the addition of the "ref" word.

Answer (score -1):

```
public bool haveEaten = false;
public bool haveDrank = false;
public bool havePlayed = false;

public void ChangeBool(int a)
{
  if(a==1)
  {
    haveEaten = true;
  }
  if(a==2)
  {
    haveDrank = true;
  }
  if(a==3)
  {
    havePlayed = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: apologies i edited my question. in regards to your solution, i suppose i would end up with many functions instead of one

    public void ChangeBool(int a)
    {
      if(a==1)
      {
        bool1 = true;
      }
    }

    public void ChangeBool(int a)
    {
      if(a==1)
      {
        bool2 = true;
      }
    }

    public void ChangeBool(int a)
    {
      if(a==1)
      {
        bool3 = true;
      }
    }

Comment: I think you didn't understand my answer. You can create multiple if statement that checks the value of the int and changes the bool accordingly. You need to pass different int values from different buttons like 1,2,3. I have edited the code for your understanding.

Comment: i see. thanks for the edit of the code. it is clearer now. my worries still remain as the code may get too long, given that there is 100 booleans. i understood from Jesse that the solution may revolve around "ref" but i cant seem to get the button to detect the function after inputting "ref". do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You can use a dictionary with string keys and Boolean values and get the key from the button.